# Coding Client socket on Flash AS3.0?

Tags: actionscript-3, sockets, actionscript, client, client-side

Now I have server code on C++ program. But I don't know how to coding client socket on Flash AS3.0.

Can you give me some example code ??

Answer (score 0):

you need the [`Socket`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/Socket.html) class if you're going to send binary data.

there's also [`XMLSocket`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/XMLSocket.html) for xml